# Why is Longest Palindromic Substring a Dynamic Programming Question?

Tags: dynamic-programming

Can someone tell me why is [Longest Palindromic Substring](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/) dynamic programming. I cannot see how we can model this question wrt to 1- Optimal Substructure. 2- Overlapping subproblems.

Comment: Did you read this? [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring)

Comment: Yeah but I wanna learn the DP perspective of it. Not Machestor algo